# r - how to assign 0 instead of "no rows selected" (dataframe 0 rows 0 columns)

Tags: mysql, r

I am trying to assign a value returned by a MySQL query to a variable in R, or 0 in case the query returns empty set (no records found). I thought I could use COALESCE like this:

```
data<-dbGetQuery(con,"COALESCE(( SELECT id FROM payments WHERE user_id=25578),0)")
```

However, I get a syntax error message:

```
RS-DBI driver: (could not run statement: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM payments WHERE user_id=25578,0)' at line 1).
```

I have been trying to find an alternative but unsuccessful. Thanks for help!

Comment: please include the whole query

Comment: It was a complete query. In the meantime I have worked around with the ifelse function. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT COALESCE(count(id) > 0,'1','0') as column_name FROM payments WHERE user_id=25578
```

If data is available for the particular id '1' will be displayed otherwise '0' will be displayed.

Comment: Thanks! I found a workaround using the R function ifelse but also used COUNT at the end. Your answer is however correct and very compact!